# Modifying ssh public key - does it matter?

Tags: openssh

When `ssh-keygen -b 4096` creates a key pair, the public key (id_rsa.pub) looks like this:

`ssh-rsa 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 user@host`

What are the practical consequences if I manually edit this public key, changing `host` to a different host name - so that `user@host` becomes `user@differenthost`? Will the key still work in the usual manner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing the base64 encoded partion will break the key... it will either become invalid or not be the pair of the private key anymore.

Changing the text at the end - `user@host` - is fine. This is the key's *comment*, and can be set while generating the key with the `-C` flag:

```
ssh-keygen -C me@mypc
```

Answer (score 2):

The part after public key is an optional *comment*.

In general, you can edit it any way you like. It does not even have to have the `user@host` format.

---

Though some uses of this syntax may impose more strict rules.

For example, when using this to setup a public key authentication in Google Compute Engine console, the comment matters. It has to be a *username* you want to use the key with.

Comment: That's an interesting restriction of GCE.

Comment: Thanks for both replies. I have asked a duplicate, but there's a little extra info provided by the answers.